# Eclipse PDT Remote System Explorer FTP not showing files

Tags: macos, eclipse-pdt, eclipse-3.5

I'm trying to set up my Eclipse PDT with Remote System Explorer. I'm on a Mac 10.5.8, and I'm using Galileo PDT. RSE is version 3.1.1.

In RSE perspective I set up a new FTP connection, set passive to true, and connect just fine, without any problems. The tree shows "MYSERVER/Files/My Home" and "MYSERVER/Files/Root". I click on root to get to my files, it says "pending..." and then nothing. It shows no files, no error messages, and I can't get to my files no matter what I do. On another server I communicate via subclipse (subversion) and it's working spectacularly, but I can't get the simple FTP connection to work.

Has anyone had this problem and been able to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem when the 'parser' property of the FTP Connector Service settings was set to a particular parser, i.e. the WinNT one. I set it to AUTO and now I can see the file listing in the tree.

One way to get to this setting: show the Remote Systems Details view, right click on your FTP connection and select Properties, go to Connector Services, then FTP Settings under FTP Connector Service in the top tree.

You may also need to set the 'passive' property to true.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up upgrading to Helios, and then my problem went away, so I can't verify if this would have worked. Thanks though, that's good information.

Comment: Ah. I forgot to mention I was on Indigo (3.7), Windows, and RSE 3.30. Not sure if Windows matters, and switching to Windows isn't a good solution anyway, but it shows that the same problem can result from simpler variations ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem (but with Zend studio). The other answer did not help. Here what I did

```
1) right click on remote connection and choose "monitor"
another block will appear showing a list of resources
2) right click on one of them (it there is `Files`, do on it) and choose
New -> Filter
3) In Folder input put / and click next
4) then write filter name(e.g. root, should not matter I think) and 
click finish.
```

if does not work, try to remove connection, create again and try the same steps again